# Rails Spring configuration similar like in Zeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zeus, rails-spring

I have something like this in Zeus custom plan, where I run some rake tasks:

```
require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails
  def rots
    `bundle exec rots 1> log/rots.log &`
  end

  def stripe_mock
    `bundle exec stripe-mock-server 1> log/stripe-mock-server.log &`
  end
end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

And Zeus config:

```
{
    "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

    "plan": {
      "boot": {
        "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
        "prerake": {"rake": []},
        "console": ["c"]
      },
      "test_environment": {
        "test_helper": {"test": ["rspec"]}
      }
    },
    "rots": {},
    "stripe_mock": {}
    }
  }
}
```

And I found this link: https://github.com/rails/spring#configuration, but I don't exactly understand how I can run and stop my custom rake tasks.

I try it something like this:

```
class CustomPlan
  def initialize
    `bundle exec rots 1> log/rots.log &`
    `bundle exec stripe-mock-server 1> log/stripe-mock-server.log &`
  end
end
CustomPlan.new
```

This works, but when I stop spring by `spring stop`, `stripe-mock-server` is not shutting down.

Is it some clever solution for running and stopping custom rake in spring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution what I came up for this moment:

```
# config/spring.rb
Spring.after_fork do
  `killall -v -9 rots & bundle exec rots 1> log/rots.log &`
  `killall -v -9 stripe-mock-server & bundle exec stripe-mock-server 1> log/stripe-mock-server.log &`
end
```

For first I kill all `rots` and `stripe-mock-server` if exists and run it again. If you find a better solution, let me know to comment. Thanks.